# How do I get doubleValue to return a decimal number more than six places?

Tags: objective-c

When the following executes:

NSString *scratchString = @".123456789";

CGFloat scratchNum = [scratchString doubleValue];

scrathNum contains 0.123457

How can I get scratchNum to contain all of the digits? No matter what I try it rounds to 6 places.

Answer (score 0):

`CGFloat` is a floating point number -- a `float` or a `double` (depending on which `typedef` is chosen by the compiler).

There's no concept of floating point numbers not "containing all of the digits". Their internal representation varies, but in this case your C `float` is represented by the [IEEE 754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).

In this case, your "rounding" is a consequence of whatever is taking that floating point number and converting it from a binary form to a textual form. This could be the Xcode IDE itself (e.g. visualizing the value in the debugger), or maybe you're using a `printf` statement and have a specific formatting specified.

Comment: I see. But I wrote a small piece of code:                                short i = 0;
    while ((scratchNum - floor(scratchNum)) != 0) {
        scratchNum = [scratchString doubleValue] * pow(10, ++i);
    }
   In this case, I = 6 at the end of the loop.  Would that be Xcode as well?